# Create email with contents in order: Text, Image, Text, Image, Text, Signature

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I am working in Excel. I want to draft an email in a specific format.

I can't find anything where an email is in this format:

- Words
- Image
- Words
- Image
- Words
- Signature

I found ones that are words, image, image and signature which I used to build mine.

This is how it appears:
[image]

This is how it should look:
[image]

I left all I tried as commented out sections.

```vb
Sub EmailGenerate()
    
    Dim objOutApp As Object, objOutMail As Object
    Dim strBody As String, strSig As String, strEnd As String, strBody2 As String
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim r As Long, r2 As Long
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection
    Dim Selection2 As Word.Selection
     
    r = shEmail.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = shEmail.Range("K1:" & Cells(r, 21).Address)
    
    r2 = shEmail.Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = shEmail.Range("W1:" & Cells(r2, 29).Address)
    
    Set objOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutMail = objOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = objOutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
     
    With objOutMail
        'If sent on behalf of another email address
        ' .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
        'Setting the email conditions
        .To = shEmail.Cells(1, 2).Value
        .CC = shEmail.Cells(2, 2).Value
        .BCC = ""
        'Checks all email names
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
        .Subject = shEmail.Cells(4, 2).Value
        'This must be visible to get the default signature
        .Display
        'Get the html code from the signature
        strSig = .htmlbody
        'This is what the email body should say
      
       ' rng.Copy
       ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.Start = Len(strBody)
       ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.End = wdDoc.Application.Selection.Start
       ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdChartPicture)
       ' wdDoc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
       ' rng2.Copy
       ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.Start = Len(strBody) + Len(strBody2)
       ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.End = wdDoc.Application.Selection.Start
       ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdChartPicture)
      
       ' rng1.Copy
       ' wdDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.PasteSpecial , , , , wdPasteBitmap
      
        rng.Copy
        wdDoc.Content.InsertParagraphBefore
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.PasteSpecial , , , , wdPasteBitmap
        wdDoc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
      
        strBody = "<Body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
          shEmail.Cells(5, 2).Value & "</p>" & _
          "<p>" & "</p>" & _
          "<p>" & shEmail.Cells(6, 2).Value & "</p>" & _
          "<p>" & shEmail.Cells(7, 2).Value & "</p>" & _
          "<p>" & "</p>" & _
          "<p>" & shEmail.Cells(8, 2).Value & "</p>"
          
        strBody2 = "<Body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
          shEmail.Cells(10, 2).Value & "</p>" & _
          "<p>" & "</p>"
       
        rng2.Copy
        wdDoc.Content.InsertParagraphBefore
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteSpecial , , , , wdPasteBitmap
        wdDoc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        
        objOutMail.htmlbody = strBody2 & _
          .htmlbody
         
        ' rng2.Copy
        ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.Start = Len(strBody) + Len(strBody2)
        ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.End = wdDoc.Application.Selection.Start
        ' wdDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdChartPicture)
    
        'Combines the email with image and the signature
        objOutMail.htmlbody = strBody & _
          .htmlbody
      
        'Automatically sends the email, should pop up briefly.
        '.Send
    
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set objOutMail = Nothing
    Set objOutApp = Nothing
     
End Sub
```

rng is the larger table and rng2 is the smaller table.

.Cells(5,2) through to (8,2) go before rng and (10,2) goes after rng and before rng2 then (12,2) would go after rng2 and before the signature.

Comment: Steven hi - the information is very clear, but I am not sure what the precise question is: Could you help me a little there? thanks

Comment: Hi John, thank you for the response.  Apologies that my question was not very clear.  I would like assistance in where my code is wrong.  Or guidance on a better way to get it into the format that i need.  I have added a brief explanation below the code to show what should go where in align with the code.  I hope that makes sense.  Thank you

Comment: one quick observation - you may know but if not `"<p>" & "</p>"` will not give you a line break, you might try `</br>`

Comment: I did not know that, thank you.

Comment: `months` and `completed` - you are looking for those to be hyperlinks? if so how are you constructing the html for that?

Comment: no that is just a string from a cell in Excel, the autocorrect just noticed i had not put `month's` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next approach. It is difficult to mix `WordEditor` with html, at least, I did not do it an I do not know how/if it can be done. Everything (I understood) you need can be done using `WordEditor` object or html using `PropertyAccessor` and link to picture paths. I am using in your adapted code only `WordEditor`:

```
Sub EmailGenerate()
 Dim objOutApp As Object, objOutMail As Object
 Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, shEmail As Worksheet
 Dim r As Long, r2 As Long
 Dim wdDoc As Word.document, wdRange As Word.Range
 
 Set shEmail = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
 
 r = shEmail.cells(Rows.count, 15).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = shEmail.Range("K1:" & cells(r, 21).Address)

 r2 = shEmail.cells(Rows.count, 23).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng2 = shEmail.Range("W1:" & cells(r2, 29).Address)

 Set objOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set objOutMail = objOutApp.CreateItem(0)
 Set wdDoc = objOutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
  
 With objOutMail
    'If sent on behalf of another email address
    '.SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    'Setting the email conditions
    .To = shEmail.cells(1, 2).Value
    .cc = shEmail.cells(2, 2).Value
    .BCC = ""
    'Checks all email names
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .subject = shEmail.cells(4, 2).Value
    'This must be visible to get the default signature
    .display 'Please, look here if its appearance is what you need.
    
    'Declare the string variables to be used:
    Dim strFrst As String, strSec As String, strThird As String, strF As String
    
    'Give values to the strings (they can take the values from the sheet...)
    strFrst = "Hello All!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    strSec = "Please, receive the picture you requested:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    strThird = "And the second picture is following:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    strF = "The last necessary string is here..." & vbCrLf
    
    'Write the first two text lines:________________
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertAfter (strFrst)
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.InsertAfter (vbCrLf) 'insert an empty line
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(3).Range.InsertAfter (strSec)
    '_______________________________________________
    
    'Embed the first picture__________________________________________
    rng.Copy
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(5).Range.PasteSpecial , , , , wdPasteBitmap
    '_________________________________________________________________
    
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(5).Range.InsertAfter (vbCrLf) 'empty line after first picture
    
    'insert the third string:_______________________
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(6).Range.InsertAfter (strThird)
    '_______________________________________________
      
    'Embed the second picture___________________________________
    rng2.Copy
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(8).Range.PasteSpecial , , , , wdPasteBitmap
    '___________________________________________________________
    
    'insert the fourth string:__________________
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(8).Range.InsertAfter (strF)
    '___________________________________________
    
    
    'Automatically sends the email, should pop up briefly.
    '.Send
 End With
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the response FaneDure, this seems to do it in this order: -
`first image`
`Hello All!`
`Please, recieve the picture you requested:`
`second image`
`And the second picture is following`
Do you know why it would come in a muddled order as this was the issue i was having? Thank you.

Comment: What i mean by my comment is, your code makes sense and flows very nicely.  But when i run it, it comes through not in the order for the code.  Any reasons why this would occur?

Comment: @Steven Byrne: This only means that I wanted to show you a way of dealing (only) with `WordEditor` in order to insert pictures or strings wherever you need. If not clear enough, I will adapt the code to insert another string at the end...

Comment: @Steven Byrne: I updated the above code to also place the last string ("The last necessary string is here...") at the end... Is this what you meant when talking about the  order?

Comment: @Steven Byrne: Do you mean that you firstly have the image and then the text? If yes, this is not happening in my case... Did you try the code **as it is**, or did some (maybe small) adjustments? Please, put a break line on `rng.Copy` and then run the code line by line (pressing F8) and see what's happening...

Comment: yes i have used you code exactly as it is.  if i do the line break at `rng.copy` it opens with my signature at the top, followed by `Hello All!`, then `please receive the picture as requested:` then if i push F8 after the break it adds everything in. But it is then in the wrong order.  Is there a reference i would need to turn on?

Comment: Is there anyway i can send a image so you can see how it appears etc.?

Comment: @Steven Byrne: Now I can understand what's happening (I think)... I do not have any signature and I couldn't check it. Try moving of `.Disply` to the very end of loop. Just before `.Send`. The signature should be added that time...

Comment: That is the same but now without the signature. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228472/discussion-between-steven-byrne-and-faneduru).

Comment: I cannot stay anymore... I should leave my office some minutes before. We can continue this discussion after some hours when I will be at home.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru i do not want to interfere with your home life so will speak tomorrow if you are available, appreciate your help.

Comment: @Steven Byrne: Please, test the updated code. I created a signature and start playing with `WordEditor` object. It works as it should I think... Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: you are a legend!!! Thank you so much! Really appreciate all your effort and all the detailed comments which will help me set this up. Will also help me understand interacting with outlook better.  Really, really appreciate it! Thank you! :-)

Comment: @Steven Byrne: Glad I could help! I also learned something during playing with `WordEditor`.  For not  know reason, adding an empty line (`vbCrLf`) will not add such a visible one, but otherwise the first paragraph will 'take' a line from the initial space between the upper mail page side and the signature row. When you need such an empty line, you must create another paragraph...

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru this will really help in this project and others I am working on :-)