# Add Range along with text in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

Below coding is working fine to send an email with the excel range. Just wanted to all "Hello**" at the top of the email Body (Left alignment). Please assist.

```
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object, wdRange As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Certificate").Range("A1:O36")
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .Display


        Set wdDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        Set wdRange = wdDoc.Range(0, 0)

              
        wdRange.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        
        
        rng.Copy
        
        
        wdRange.Paste


        DoEvents

        Set wdRange = wdDoc.Range(0, wdDoc.Characters.Count)

        'wdRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

        For i = 1 To wdRange.Tables.Count
            wdRange.Tables(i).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
        Next i
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: A similar question was asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114347/excel-email-text-image-text-image-text-signature

Answer (score 0):

Try the next way, please:

```
Sub sendOutlookMail()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object, wdRange As Object
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Certificate").Range("A1:O36")
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .subject = "Subject"
        .display

        Set wdDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        With wdDoc
            .Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertAfter ("Hello!" & vbCrLf)
            
            rng.Copy
            .Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not working. Once Range is pasted, Hello word get disappeared

Comment: gaus shaikh: Did you use the code as it  is? Do you have ` & vbCrLf` after "Hello!"? If yes, do you have a signature for the used account?

Comment: gaus shaikh: Still alive?